# SQL: Joining two tables with repeating count for each row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

3 tables in a music website database:

**user**(*user_id, name, password*)

**track**(*track_id, title*)

**user_likes_this_track** ( *user_id, track_id* )

When some particular user is logged in. Using PHP and MySQL and JSON API, I can check from the last table what songs the user like..

```
SELECT * FROM `track` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `track_id` FROM `user_likes_this_track` WHERE `user_id` = '$logged_user_id' )
```

I also wanted to show an emoji at the client side application for a particular song. if he likes it to show the like emoji resource, and if he doesn't like the song to show the other resource. And this query did the job:

```
SELECT COUNT(`track_id`) AS `liked` FROM `user_likes_this_track` 
        WHERE `user_id` = '$logged_user_id'
        AND `track_id` = '$track_id';
```

**Liked** will be **1** if the user likes the song and **0** if he doesn't

But, the problem is when he go for a search filtered list with tracks he might have liked or not.

From the **user perspective**, I'm trying to get a combination of **track_id**, **track_title**, **liked** from the Search Result or even all tracks to get something like:

```
track_id, title,  liked
1       ,'ZHU...' , 1         // he likes this song
2       ,'Sia...' , 1         // he likes SIA too
3       ,'other.' , 0         // 0 occurrence in user_likes_this_track
...
```

Is it possible to find a magic query for this solution without altering and adding extra tables?

Thank you all for your precious time.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want a list of tracks where the user has expressed a preference one way or the other? Surely that would be `select * from user_likes_this_track left join track on track_id = id where user_id = your user` or similar? That would give all tracks they have liked or not liked.

Comment: @droopsnoot yes and also the ones he hasn't preferred with both showing the preference state.. but your code is showing only prefererenced..

Comment: I appreciate it thanks a lot guys answers are working.. but I see both ways are using two states approach.. isn't this possible with count() function?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the structure of the 'likes' table. For some reason I'd decided that if the user liked the track it would write a '1', and if they disliked the track it would write a '0', and any that are not in the table are those that the user has no opinion on. Your structure seems to be that if the user has an entry in the 'likes' table they like the track, but if they do not, you are presuming the opposite. My query above won't do anything for that, you're quite correct. I must read these things in more detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
$sql = "SELECT track_id, title, 1 as liked from track where track_id NOT IN (SELECT track_id from user_likes_this_track where user_id = '$logged_user_id') UNION SELECT track_id, title, 0 as liked from track where track_id IN (SELECT track_id from user_likes_this_track where user_id = '$logged_user_id')";
```

Comment: Well that's tricky and simple.. I thought count() will be part of the solution the whole time.but it's getting reversed NOT IN should be at 0 part.. and IN at 1

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    a.track_id, 
    a.title, 
    CASE 
        WHEN b.track_id IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END
FROM track a
LEFT JOIN user_likes_this_track b ON b.track_id = a.track_id
    AND b.user_id = :userID
;
```

Comment: I tried your code 3 times and still getting an error then remembered that 'like' is a reserved word..  then it worked I didn't know what 'CASE' 'END' is..

Comment: Changed _like_ to _b_.

Comment: Thanks mate I thought I'd be stuck forever. I was wondering isn't there a way doing this with count()